# "Cupyx.scipy.sparse" problem: "cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError:an illegal memory access was encountered"

Tags: scipy, cupy

Take summary, we try to do human segmentation on a social media video using an unsupervised deep CNN. The processing extract each video frame (using OpenCV). The video frame is segmented by a CNN to output a coarse mask. Then, a bilateral filter is used to extract the accurate mask with video frame and coarse mask. We use cupy and cupyx.scipy.sparse to build the bilateral filter. The bilateral filter source code is in below:

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "/usr/local/cuda/lib64"

from cupyx.scipy.sparse import diags
from cupyx.scipy.sparse.linalg import cg
from cupyx.scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from cupyx.scipy import ndimage
import cupy as np

from skimage.io import imread
import PIL.Image as Image 

RGB_TO_YUV = np.array([
    [ 0.299,     0.587,     0.114],
    [-0.168736, -0.331264,  0.5],
    [ 0.5,      -0.418688, -0.081312]])
YUV_TO_RGB = np.array([
    [1.0,  0.0,      1.402],
    [1.0, -0.34414, -0.71414],
    [1.0,  1.772,    0.0]])
YUV_OFFSET = np.array([0, 128.0, 128.0]).reshape(1, 1, -1)
MAX_VAL = 255.0
def rgb2yuv(im):
    return np.tensordot(im, RGB_TO_YUV, ([2], [1])) + YUV_OFFSET

def yuv2rgb(im):
    return np.tensordot(im.astype(float) - YUV_OFFSET, YUV_TO_RGB, ([2], [1]))

def get_valid_idx(valid, candidates):
    """Find which values are present in a list and where they are located"""
    locs = np.searchsorted(valid, candidates)
    # Handle edge case where the candidate is larger than all valid values
    locs = np.clip(locs, 0, len(valid) - 1)
    # Identify which values are actually present
    valid_idx = np.flatnonzero(valid[locs] == candidates)
    locs = locs[valid_idx] 
    return valid_idx, locs

class BilateralGrid(object):
    def __init__(self, im, sigma_spatial=32, sigma_luma=8, sigma_chroma=8):
        im_yuv = rgb2yuv(im)
        # Compute 5-dimensional XYLUV bilateral-space coordinates
        Iy, Ix = np.mgrid[:im.shape[0], :im.shape[1]]
        x_coords = (Ix / sigma_spatial).astype(int)
        y_coords = (Iy / sigma_spatial).astype(int)
        luma_coords = (im_yuv[..., 0] /sigma_luma).astype(int)
        chroma_coords = (im_yuv[..., 1:] / sigma_chroma).astype(int)
        coords = np.dstack((x_coords, y_coords, luma_coords, chroma_coords))
        coords_flat = coords.reshape(-1, coords.shape[-1])
        self.npixels, self.dim = coords_flat.shape
        # Hacky "hash vector" for coordinates,
        # Requires all scaled coordinates be < MAX_VAL
        self.hash_vec = (MAX_VAL**np.arange(self.dim))
        # Construct S and B matrix
        self._compute_factorization(coords_flat)
    
    def _compute_factorization(self, coords_flat):
        # Hash each coordinate in grid to a unique value
        hashed_coords = self._hash_coords(coords_flat)
        unique_hashes, unique_idx, idx = \
            np.unique(hashed_coords, return_index=True, return_inverse=True) 
        # Identify unique set of vertices
        unique_coords = coords_flat[unique_idx]
        self.nvertices = len(unique_coords)
        # Construct sparse splat matrix that maps from pixels to vertices
        self.S = csr_matrix((np.ones(self.npixels), (idx, np.arange(self.npixels))))
        # Construct sparse blur matrices.
        # Note that these represent [1 0 1] blurs, excluding the central element
        self.blurs = []
        for d in range(self.dim):
            blur = 0.0
            for offset in (-1, 1):
                offset_vec = np.zeros((1, self.dim))
                offset_vec[:, d] = offset
                neighbor_hash = self._hash_coords(unique_coords + offset_vec)
                valid_coord, idx = get_valid_idx(unique_hashes, neighbor_hash)
                blur = blur + csr_matrix((np.ones((len(valid_coord),)),
                                          (valid_coord, idx)),
                                         shape=(self.nvertices, self.nvertices))
            self.blurs.append(blur)
    
    def _hash_coords(self, coord):
        """Hacky function to turn a coordinate into a unique value"""
        return np.dot(coord.reshape(-1, self.dim), self.hash_vec)

    def splat(self, x):
        return self.S.dot(x)

    def slice(self, y):
        return self.S.T.dot(y)

    def blur(self, x):
        """Blur a bilateral-space vector with a 1 2 1 kernel in each dimension"""
        assert x.shape[0] == self.nvertices
        out = 2 * self.dim * x
        for blur in self.blurs:
            out = out + blur.dot(x)
        return out

    def filter(self, x):
        """Apply bilateral filter to an input x"""
        return self.slice(self.blur(self.splat(x))) /  \
               self.slice(self.blur(self.splat(np.ones_like(x))))

def bistochastize(grid, maxiter=10):
    """Compute diagonal matrices to bistochastize a bilateral grid"""
    m = grid.splat(np.ones(grid.npixels))
    n = np.ones(grid.nvertices)
    for i in range(maxiter):
        n = np.sqrt(n * m / grid.blur(n))
    # Correct m to satisfy the assumption of bistochastization regardless
    # of how many iterations have been run.
    m = n * grid.blur(n)
    Dm = diags(m, 0)
    Dn = diags(n, 0)
    return Dn, Dm

class BilateralSolver(object):
    def __init__(self, grid, params):
        self.grid = grid
        self.params = params
        self.Dn, self.Dm = bistochastize(grid)

    def solve(self, x, w):
        # Check that w is a vector or a nx1 matrix
        if w.ndim == 2:
            assert(w.shape[1] == 1)
        elif w.dim == 1:
            w = w.reshape(w.shape[0], 1)
        A_smooth = (self.Dm - self.Dn.dot(self.grid.blur(self.Dn)))
        w_splat = self.grid.splat(w)
        A_data = diags(w_splat[:,0], 0)
        A = self.params["lam"] * A_smooth + A_data
        xw = x * w
        b = self.grid.splat(xw)
        # Use simple Jacobi preconditioner
        A_diag = np.maximum(A.diagonal(), self.params["A_diag_min"])
        M = diags(1 / A_diag, 0)
        # Flat initialization
        y0 = self.grid.splat(xw) / w_splat
        yhat = np.empty_like(y0)
        for d in range(x.shape[-1]):
            yhat[..., d], info = cg(A, b[..., d], x0=y0[..., d], M=M, maxiter=self.params["cg_maxiter"], tol=self.params["cg_tol"])
        xhat = self.grid.slice(yhat)
        return xhat

import cv2
def bilateral_solver_videout(img, target, sigma_spatial = 24, sigma_luma = 4, sigma_chroma = 4) : 
    
    reference = np.array(img)
    h_img, w_img = reference.shape[:2]
    h, w = target.shape

    if w_img != w or h_img != h:
        target = cv2.resize(target, (w_img, h_img))
        w, h = w_img, h_img

    confidence = np.ones((h, w)) * 0.999

    grid_params = {
        'sigma_luma' : sigma_luma, # Brightness bandwidth
        'sigma_chroma': sigma_chroma, # Color bandwidth
        'sigma_spatial': sigma_spatial # Spatial bandwidth
    }

    bs_params = {
        'lam': 256, # The strength of the smoothness parameter
        'A_diag_min': 1e-5, # Clamp the diagonal of the A diagonal in the Jacobi preconditioner.
        'cg_tol': 1e-5, # The tolerance on the convergence in PCG
        'cg_maxiter': 25 # The number of PCG iterations
    }

    grid = BilateralGrid(reference, **grid_params)
    target = np.array(target) # if use cupy, convert to cupy calss
    t = target.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.double) 
    c = confidence.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.double) 

    ## output solver, which is a soft value
    output_solver = BilateralSolver(grid, bs_params).solve(t, c).reshape((h, w))

    binary_solver = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(output_solver>0.5)
    labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(binary_solver) 

    nb_pixel = [np.sum(labeled == i) for i in range(nr_objects + 1)]
    nb_pixel = np.array(nb_pixel) # if use cupy, convert to cupy calss
    pixel_order = np.argsort(nb_pixel)
    try : 
    binary_solver = labeled == pixel_order[-2]
    except: 
        binary_solver = np.ones((h, w), dtype=bool)

    output_solver = np.asnumpy(output_solver)
    binary_solver = np.asnumpy(binary_solver)

    return output_solver, binary_solver
```

When we run CNN (using PyTorch) and bilateral filter (use Cupy) on social media videos. The cupy report errors:

```
frame count: 1
Segmenter process time: 0.00971531867980957    
Bilateral process time: 0.10550689697265625
Auto treshold after bilateral process time: 0.0067441463470458984
frame count: 2
Segmenter process time: 0.009685277938842773
Bilateral process time: 0.10308218002319336
Auto treshold after bilateral process time: 0.006288051605224609
frame count: 3
    Segmenter process time: 0.00954747200012207
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/cusparse.pyx", line 1544, in     cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.CuSparseError: CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
Exception ignored in: 'cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.spGEMM_workEstimation'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/cusparse.pyx", line 1544, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.CuSparseError: CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zheng/Zyetric/MoveV2/process_video.py", line 210, in <module>
    mask = mtmnet.segmentation(frame)
  File "/home/zheng/Zyetric/MoveV2/process_video.py", line 135, in segmentation
   mask_bisolver, binary_solver = bilateral_solver.bilateral_solver_videout(
  File "/home/zheng/Zyetric/MoveV2/bilateral_solver.py", line 299, in bilateral_solver_videout
    output_solver = BilateralSolver(grid, bs_params).solve(t, c).reshape((h, w))
  File "/home/zheng/Zyetric/MoveV2/bilateral_solver.py", line 187, in solve
    A_smooth = (self.Dm - self.Dn.dot(self.grid.blur(self.Dn)))
  File "/home/zheng/anaconda3/envs/move/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupyx/scipy/sparse/_base.py", line 338, in dot
    return self @ other
  File "/home/zheng/anaconda3/envs/move/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupyx/scipy/sparse/_base.py", line 127, in __matmul__
    return self.__mul__(other)
  File "/home/zheng/anaconda3/envs/move/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupyx/scipy/sparse/_base.py", line 110, in __mul__
    return self.tocsr().__mul__(other)
  File "/home/zheng/anaconda3/envs/move/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupyx/scipy/sparse/_csr.py", line 156, in __mul__
    return cusparse.spgemm(self, other)
  File "/home/zheng/anaconda3/envs/move/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cupyx/cusparse.py", line 2081, in spgemm
    _cusparse.spGEMM_copy(
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/cusparse.pyx", line 4991, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.spGEMM_copy
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/cusparse.pyx", line 4999, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.spGEMM_copy
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/cusparse.pyx", line 1544, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.libs.cusparse.CuSparseError: CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
      File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
    cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in     cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory  access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in  cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in  cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory     access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory   access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in    cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
 cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Exception ignored in: 'cupy.cuda.function.Module.__dealloc__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 217, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.moduleUnload
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/api/driver.pyx", line 60, in cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.api.driver.CUDADriverError: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS: an illegal memory access was encountered
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
```

We try to change "from cupyx.scipy.sparse import diags" to use "from cupy import diag as diags". However, it gives other memory problems. We also try:

`import cupy as np`

`np.cuda.set_allocator(np.cuda.MemoryPool(np.cuda.malloc_managed).malloc)`

However, it still not working.

We test it with 19 social media videos. video format is ".mp4". Two videos have resolution 4K, 17 videos are 1920x1080. Different video stuck in different frames. The output above shows a video's processing example, in 3rd frame, the error happens. However, the same video stuck in the same frame. The video output above always has problem in the 3rd frame.

Our SYSTEM info.:

Ubuntu 22.04;
CUDA 11.6;
Conda 22.11.1;

Conda enviroment:

```
python 3.9.16
cupy 12.0.0 (install by using $conda install -c conda-forge cupy)
cudatoolkit 11.6
cudnn 8.3.2.0
pytorch 1.12.1
scipy 1.10.0
scikit-image 0.19.3
numpy 1.23.5
```

Does anyone know the problem and the solutions?